# how to switch between cluster types in Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I'm trying to switch cluster manager from standalone to 'YARN' in Apache Spark that I've installed for learning.

I read following [thread to understand which cluster type should be chosen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664834/which-cluster-type-should-i-choose-for-spark)

However, I'd like to know the steps/syntax to change the cluster type.
Ex: from Standalone to YARN or from YARN to Standalone.

Comment: What's about your hardware/software? YARN is independent from Spark resource manager, suitable for many others applications. As I know, YARN is not provided with Spark, so you must ensure, YARN is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spark there is one function name as `--master` that can helps you to execute your script on yarn Cluster mode or standalone mode.

Run the application on local mode or standalone used this with `spark-submit` command

```
--master Local[*]
```

or

```
  --master spark://192.168.10.01:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
```

Run on a YARN cluster

```
 --master yarn 
 --deploy-mode cluster
```

For more information kindly visit this link.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are not running through command line then you can directly set this master on SparkConf object.

```
sparkConf.setMaster(http://path/to/master/url:port) in cluster mode
```

or

```
sparkConf.setMaster(local[*]) in client/local mode
```